# Any reason I am getting back the query name in the GraphQL results?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo, apollo-server

Using the `makeExecutableSchema` with the following Query definition:

```
# Interface for simple presence in front-end.
type AccountType {
    email: Email!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
}

# The Root Query
type Query {
    # Get's the account per ID or with an authToken.
    getAccount(
        email: Email
    )   : AccountType!
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

And the following resolver:

```
export default {
    Query: {
        async getAccount(_, {email}, { authToken }) {
            /**
             * Authentication
             */
            //const user = security.requireAuth(authToken)

            /**
             * Resolution
             */
            const account = await accounts.find({email})
            if (account.length !== 1) {
                throw new GraphQLError('No account was found with the given email.', GraphQLError.codes.GRAPHQL_NOT_FOUND)
            }
            return account
        }
    }
}
```

When I query with:

```
query {
  getAccount(email: "test@testing.com") {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

I am getting the following result in GraphiQL:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getAccount": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }
  }
}
```

So, any reason I am getting this "getAccount" back in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `getAccount` **is not** a query name. It's just a regular field on the root query type `Query`.

And having results on **the exact same shape** as the query is one of the core design principles of GraphQL:

[image]
*Screenshot from http://graphql.org/ site*

Query name in GraphQL goes after `query` keyword:

```
query myQueryName {
  getAccount(email: "test@testing.com") {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, this makes sense but brings up another question about creating more than one query name with `makeExecutableSchema`. Right now I am just polluting the root `Query` across the backend. How would you go about this? Or are you supposed to define queries as part of the (AccountType, in this case) type?

Comment: In fact. I just tried testing this by pulling the query into the type definition via `extend` in another file (that I was using for extending the `Query`), but got `"Cannot query field \"getAccount\" on type \"Query\"." when trying `query Account { getAccount(email: "test@testing.com") { firstName lastName } }`